# XPath expression for finding an element without a particular attribute

Tags: c#, xpath

I have an xml file with the following format

```
<someXML>
    <a>
        <b></b>
        <b test='someValue'></b>
    </a>

    <c>
        <d test='someOtherValue'></d>
        <d></d>
    </c>
</someXML>
```

I'm trying to write C# code that will get me a node set containing only those nodes with the test attribute. I am trying to use an XPathExpression in this manner:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("someXML");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression expression = XPathExpression.Compile("//*[@test]");
object nodeSet = navigator.Evaluate(expression);
```

This doesn't seem to be working. When I debug, the nodeSet always contains the Root element. Is there something wrong with the expression or is this working correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you assume that the `nodeSet` contains the “Root” element because the debugger displays its string representation as `Position=0, Current={Root}`? That may be misleading; the reason that the “Root” element appears is because the `XPathNodeIterator` (which is the actual type returned by `Evaluate` in your case) has not yet been positioned on the first node resulting from the query. Per the MSDN documentation for [`XPathNodeIterator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.aspx):

> > An `XPathNodeIterator` object returned by the `XPathNavigator` class is not positioned on the first node in a selected set of nodes. A call to the `MoveNext` method of the `XPathNodeIterator` class must be made to position the `XPathNodeIterator` object on the first node in the selected set of nodes.

You can retrieve your path items by iterating over your `nodeSet`:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("someXML");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression expression = XPathExpression.Compile("//*[@test]");
XPathNodeIterator nodeSet = (XPathNodeIterator)navigator.Evaluate(expression);
foreach (XPathItem item in nodeSet)
{
    // Process item here
}
```

Or, if you want them converted to an array:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("someXML");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression expression = XPathExpression.Compile("//*[@test]");
XPathNodeIterator nodeSet = (XPathNodeIterator)navigator.Evaluate(expression);
XPathItem[] items = nodeSet.Cast<XPathItem>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Your XPath **does work**, it's just you need to retrieve nodes a bit differently:

```
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression expression = XPathExpression.Compile("//*[@test]");
var matchedNodes = navigator.Select(expression);
foreach (XPathNavigator node in matchedNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.UnderlyingObject);
}
```

Snippet above will print the following:

```
<b test='someValue'></b>
<d test='someOtherValue'></d>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your expression is seems to be correct. But you could use [`XPathSelectElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathselectelements.aspx) extension method to do it simplier:

```
var nodes = document.XPathSelectElements("//*[@test]");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath query is correct. The Current member will be the Root element (I'm not an XPathIterator expert, so I don't really know the rationale behind it). If you iterate through your nodeSet, you will only get the matches to your XPath query. So I guess the answer is to iterate the set and put each item into a collection.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll want to use the Select method of the XPathNavigator object, instead of Evaluate, which will return an XPathNodeIterator object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tk3f03k.aspx

or you could use the XmlDocument object and XmlNodeList:

```
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load("somexml.xml");

        XmlNodeList nodeList = document.SelectNodes("//*[@test]");

        foreach (XmlNode Node in nodeList) { 
            // do something.            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this, assuming that you just want the nodes and don't have some specific reason to use the navigator (null checking elided):

```
var document = XDocument.Load("someXML");
var myNodes = document.Descendants().Where(node => node.Attribute(myAttributeName) != null);
```

It doesn't use the navigator, but it's pretty simple and straightforward if you just want the nodes.